# Problem restoring windows with Google Drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive, windows

I have a kinda of tricky issue. I was about to use a bootable pen drive to restore my PC and keep my files, but I can't find an answer anywhere. Well, in restore options, if I choose to keep my files, the description says that program and configurations will be deleted and my files will be kept, but Google Drive in my windows is considered a file or a program? If I choose to keep my files, Google drive will be gone?

Comment: Since you seem to be asking about the file synchronization feature of Google Drive, rather than the web interface, your question is more appropriate for [su].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have done a file synchronization with your personal Google Drive web application recently, then all your files in Google Drive are stored on Google's servers. These files which are stored on Google's servers will not be deleted from your Google Drive web application if you restore your PC.